# Adding click event to empty span block

Tags: jquery

I have some html form

```
<div id="1">
    <div>
    <span class="checkbox" style="background-position: 0pt -34px;"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Adelaide" class="styled" name="sidecity" id="sidecity-control-name-0">
    <label for="sidecity-control-name-0">Adelaide</label>
    </div>       
</div>
```

How to add click event handler to empty span block ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
$('span.checkbox').click(function(e) {
    // do something here to handle a click event on your span
});
```

However, unless the `checkbox` class does something really special, that element isn't likely to take up any space on the page, so chances of it being clicked on are slim to none.

Comment: Does not work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNRU3/)

Comment: @Victor, what are you expecting? Your span is empty - where do you expect to click to fire the event? Also, your fiddle doesn't include jQuery. I suggest going back to the drawing board and rethinking your goal/requirements.

Comment: I use [customformelements](http://customformelements.net/) and I need to put a handler on the checkbox, but it turns out only on the label.

Comment: @Victor, you tagged jQuery, not MooTools...